# How can I embed Drupal content in a widget on an external site?

Tags: drupal, widget, embed, external

I tried several approaches with the modules I found, but none of them seems to be able to do what I want!

I have a site R (remote) on which I want to integrate the content (posts with comments and possibility to leave a new one, forum, wiki) of a Drupal site D.
My idea is to have a widget on R, containing REST calls to D, but this approach seems to require a little too much effort in the rendering of that content.

How else can I do?
What in your opinion is the best approach?

Unlucky I can't use an iframe :( (I need something of asyncronous and reliable also in case the required content is not available)

Any help would be extremely appreciated, and I would be extremely thankful :)

- Riccardo

Answer (score 0):

If you cant use an iframe then [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module is definitely the way to go. The [Services Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views) module is very useful to harness the power of views to give you a nice clean output.

Comment: Thank you very much, this module will be very helpful!

Comment: Yes! The documentation provided is very helpful, and the module is easy to use and powerful.

I'm modifying the Services module in order to change the authentication through a provided token to verify through an external SOAP service, and I am adding custom behaviors on resource updates. For example, through an update of a comment I can increment the number of likes, and so on.
If you think it might be useful to describe the approach I adopted, I'll write a little how to, even though I really think that the infrastructure I have to work on has serious issues!!.. it doesn't make a lot of sense!